# How to add type script variable on angular HTML editor content

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to create dynamic letter in angular using HTML editor. Also I need to add  some variable from type script in HTML editor content

[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcykp.png)

when I view this letter I want to set value for this {{NAME}} variable from type script. Can some one help me ? This is my fist question in stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

The image I can see, is not a html editor rather it's a content editor. Please use template interpolation in html editor where you've html tag
like

my name is {{first_name}}

where first_name is your dynamic variable..
Hope you can understand what I mean to say.